# hibernate and Sybase error

Tags: java, hibernate, sybase, cross-join

I use hibernate and sybase in my project,the sql which generated by hibernate used cross join,but sybase do not support cross join,can anyone tell me how can I avoid cross join?
  thanks

Answer (score 1):

There exists a [Hibernate Bugreport](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5356) about this issue.

One possible Workaround  may be to use the `Sybase11Dialect` or `SybaseASE15Dialect`